# Emacs lisp format doesn't print to *scratch*?

Tags: print, scratch-buffer, format

I've got this function

```
(defun mt ()
    (dotimes (x 20)
      (dotimes (y 20)
        (format "%3d " (* (1+ x) (1+ y))))
      (format "\n")))
```

in my `*scratch*`. a `Ctr-=` prints back `mt`. But then evaluating `(mt)` only prints back `nil`. How would I get it to print out the multiplication table? This works in Common Lisp at the REPL. I know I'm missing something basic here...

Comment: Emacs Lisp `(format "%..." ...)` is equivalent to Common Lisp `(format nil "%..." ...)`. See also [(elisp) Output Streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Streams.html) and [(elisp) Output Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Functions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format` generates a string, but it doesn't do anything with it. You probably want to pass the result of `format` on to something that does:

```
(defun mt ()
  (dotimes (x 20)
    (dotimes (y 20)
      (insert (format "%3d " (* (1+ x) (1+ y)))))
    (insert (format "\n"))))
```

## UPDATE

I think you're also confused about how `dotimes` works. From the doc string:

> (dotimes (VAR COUNT [**RESULT**]) BODY...)
>
> :around advice: ‘cl--wrap-in-nil-block’
>
> Loop a certain number of times.
>   Evaluate BODY with VAR bound to successive integers running from 0,
>   inclusive, to COUNT, exclusive.  **Then evaluate RESULT to get
>   the return value** (**nil** if **RESULT is omitted**).

Without a `results` argument, `dotimes` will only produce side-effects (modifying variables or state) if you explicitly tell it to, as I have above by adding the `insert` forms. If you add a `results` argument, you can use that variable to return a value.

To get the behaviour you expect, we need to add `result` and some code to modify it:

```
(defun mt ()
  (let ((res ""))
    (dotimes (x 20 res)
      (dotimes (y 20)
        (setq res
              (concat res (format "%3d " (* (1+ x) (1+ y))))))
      (setq res
            (concat res (format "\n"))))))
```

This form will return the table you have constructed, which you can then do what you like with.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But why does something like this `(format "%5d is padded on the left with spaces" (+ 1 3))` produce output in *scratch* and my `mt` function not?

Comment: @147pm What typing `C-j` in the scratch buffer does is evaluate the previous expression, convert that value to a string and then insert the string into the scratch buffer. So it's `C-j` that does the actual adding of text to the scratch buffer; merely evaluating `(format ...)` (as happens when a function calls `format`) just makes a string (in your computer's memory somewhere) but doesn't insert the string in any buffer.

Comment: Oh right. I have rebound `C-j` in scratch, so I don't get the default behaviour anymore. I've been using `eval-last-sexp`, not `eval-print-last-sexp`.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the closest we'll get, Omar and Tyler. Not sure the logic of having `eval-last-sexp` and `eval-print-last-sexp` but someone must have considered keeping the behaviors separate important and useful...

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a different approach, using `mapconcat` to apply the function and concatenate the results:

```
(let ((range (number-sequence 1 20)))
  (mapconcat
   (lambda (y)
     (mapconcat
      (lambda (x)
        (format "%03d" (* x y)))
      range " "))
   range "\n"))
```

This returns the string that you can `insert` or whatever else.

Comment: Again, this plugged into *scratch* or the REPL prints out the table just fine. What's the difference between this code and my `mt` function other than mine's a function?

Comment: `dotimes` returns the value of the third element of its first argument after finishing the iterations, it doesn't evaluate it for each iteration.